# How to make animations on swing faster and smooth

Tags: java, swing, animation

Im doing a kind of color transition (going from the start color of a gradient to the end color and from the end color to the start, that indefinitely) but I cannot find the way to make a fast and smooth color transition, either smooth but slow or fast but laggy, how can I do it?

What rate of change does is to change the limits of the gradient in order to move.

Swing Timer to make the color transition:

```
            Timer t2 = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() { // I want to make this animation to happen faster and smoothly

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Rate of change on timer: " + rateOfChange);
                rateOfChange += 30;
                if (rateOfChange > mainWidth + 100) {
                    rateOfChange = 0;
                    switchEvenOdd++;
                }
                if (switchEvenOdd % 2 == 0)
                    switchGradient = false;
                else
                    switchGradient = true;
                repaint();
            }

        });
        t2.setInitialDelay(0);
        t2.setRepeats(true);
        t2.start();
```

Timer to update the clock each second:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                hourLeft = (hour / 10) % 10;
                hourRight = (hour % 10);
                minuteLeft = (minutes / 10) % 10;
                minuteRight = (minutes % 10);
                secondLeft = (seconds / 10) % 10;
                secondRight = (seconds % 10);
                // System.out.println("Hour: " + hour + " Minutes: " + minutes + " Seconds: " +
                // seconds);

                dotsIluminated++;

            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
```

Gradient Definition (skip the gradients with colorOff):

```
        private GradientPaint getColor(byte val, int shift) {
        int a = 255 * (val >> shift) & 1;
        if (!switchGradient) {
            if (a == 0)
                return new GradientPaint(0, 0, colorOff, (int) mainWidth, (int) mainHeight, colorOff);
            else {
                actualGradient = new GradientPaint(0, 0, colorStart, 1 + rateOfChange, 1 + rateOfChange, colorEnd);
                return actualGradient;
            }
        } else {
            if (a == 0)
                return new GradientPaint(0, 0, colorOff, (int) mainWidth, (int) mainHeight, colorOff);
            else {
                actualGradient = new GradientPaint(0, 0, colorEnd, 1 + rateOfChange, 1 + rateOfChange, colorStart);
                return actualGradient;
            }
        }
    }
```

Example with the updated code:

(Gradient from RGB: 29, 43, 100 to RGB: 248, 205, 218)
[image]

Whole source code (700 lines and a bad design):

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private CustomRectangle custRect = null;
private JButton btnCancel;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

public MainWindow() {
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setSize(1130, 350);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    custRect = new CustomRectangle(1130, 350);
    getContentPane().add(custRect);
    getContentPane().add(getBtnCancel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

private Color complementaryColor(Color background) {
    int alpha = background.getAlpha();
    int red = background.getRed();
    int blue = background.getBlue();
    int green = background.getGreen();

    // find compliments
    red = (~red) & 0xff;
    blue = (~blue) & 0xff;
    green = (~green) & 0xff;

    return new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);
}

private JButton getBtnCancel() {
    if (btnCancel == null) {
        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setBackground(null);
        btnCancel.setBorder(null);
        btnCancel.setForeground(complementaryColor(getContentPane().getBackground()));
        btnCancel.setFocusPainted(false);
    }
    return btnCancel;
}

private class CustomRectangle extends JComponent {

    private byte[] nums = new byte[] { 0x7E, 0x30, 0x6D, 0x79, 0x33, 0x5B, 0x5F, 0x70, 0x7F, 0x7B };

    private double mainWidth = 0.0;
    private double mainHeight = 0.0;

    private boolean switchGradient = false;

    private double XbHL;
    private double widthbHL;
    private double YbHL;
    private double heightbHL;

    private double XcHL;
    private double widthcHL;
    private double YcHL;
    private double heightcHL;

    private double[][][] originalCoordinates;

    private double heightcML;
    private double YcML;
    private double widthcML;
    private double XcML;

    private double XbML;
    private double YbML;
    private double widthbML;
    private double heightbML;

    private int hourLeft;
    private int hourRight;
    private int minuteLeft;
    private int minuteRight;
    private int secondLeft;
    private int secondRight;
    private int dotsIluminated = 1;
    private int switchEvenOdd = 0;

    private Color colorStart = new Color(29, 43, 100);
    private Color colorEnd = new Color(248, 205, 218);

    private Color colorOff = new Color(15, 15, 15);

    private int rateOfChange = 0;

    private static final double offset = 140.0;

    private GradientPaint actualGradient;

    public CustomRectangle(int width, int height) {
        mainWidth = width;
        mainHeight = height;

        originalCoordinates = new double[7][2][2];

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                hourLeft = (hour / 10) % 10;
                hourRight = (hour % 10);
                minuteLeft = (minutes / 10) % 10;
                minuteRight = (minutes % 10);
                secondLeft = (seconds / 10) % 10;
                secondRight = (seconds % 10);
                // System.out.println("Hour: " + hour + " Minutes: " + minutes + " Seconds: " +
                // seconds);

                repaint();
                dotsIluminated++;

            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();

        Timer t2 = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() { // I want to make this animation to happen faster and smoothly

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Rate of change on timer: " + rateOfChange);
                rateOfChange += 30;
                if (rateOfChange > mainWidth + 100) {
                    rateOfChange = 0;
                    switchEvenOdd++;
                }
                if (switchEvenOdd % 2 == 0)
                    switchGradient = false;
                else
                    switchGradient = true;
            }

        });
        t2.setInitialDelay(0);
        t2.setRepeats(true);
        t2.start();

    }

    public byte[] getNums() {
        return nums;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        generalCall(g2d, hourLeft, hourRight, minuteLeft, minuteRight, secondLeft, secondRight);

    }

    public void generalCall(Graphics2D g2d, int hoursLeft, int hoursRight, int minutesLeft, int minutesRight,
            int secondsLeft, int secondsRight) {
        // Hours
        drawAHoursHigh(g2d, nums[hoursLeft], 0);
        drawBHoursHigh(g2d, nums[hoursLeft], 0);
        drawCHoursHigh(g2d, nums[hoursLeft], 0);
        drawDHoursHigh(g2d, nums[hoursLeft], 0);
        drawEHoursHigh(g2d, nums[hoursLeft], 0);
        drawFHoursHigh(g2d, nums[hoursLeft], 0);
        drawGHoursHigh(g2d, nums[hoursLeft], 0);

        drawAHoursLow(g2d, nums[hoursRight], offset);
        drawBHoursLow(g2d, nums[hoursRight], offset);
        drawCHoursLow(g2d, nums[hoursRight], offset);
        drawDHoursLow(g2d, nums[hoursRight], offset);
        drawEHoursLow(g2d, nums[hoursRight], offset);
        drawFHoursLow(g2d, nums[hoursRight], offset);
        drawGHoursLow(g2d, nums[hoursRight], offset);

        drawPointUp(g2d, 2.5 * offset);
        drawPointDown(g2d, 2.5 * offset);

        // Minutes
        drawAMinutesHigh(g2d, nums[minutesLeft], 2.8 * offset);
        drawBMinutesHigh(g2d, nums[minutesLeft], 2.8 * offset);
        drawCMinutesHigh(g2d, nums[minutesLeft], 2.8 * offset);
        drawDMinutesHigh(g2d, nums[minutesLeft], 2.8 * offset);
        drawEMinutesHigh(g2d, nums[minutesLeft], 2.8 * offset);
        drawFMinutesHigh(g2d, nums[minutesLeft], 2.8 * offset);
        drawGMinutesHigh(g2d, nums[minutesLeft], 2.8 * offset);

        drawAMinutesLow(g2d, nums[minutesRight], 3.8 * offset);
        drawBMinutesLow(g2d, nums[minutesRight], 3.8 * offset);
        drawCMinutesLow(g2d, nums[minutesRight], 3.8 * offset);
        drawDMinutesLow(g2d, nums[minutesRight], 3.8 * offset);
        drawEMinutesLow(g2d, nums[minutesRight], 3.8 * offset);
        drawFMinutesLow(g2d, nums[minutesRight], 3.8 * offset);
        drawGMinutesLow(g2d, nums[minutesRight], 3.8 * offset);

        drawPointSUp(g2d, 5.3 * offset);
        drawPointSDown(g2d, 5.3 * offset);

        // Seconds
        drawASecondsHigh(g2d, nums[secondsLeft], 5.6 * offset);
        drawBSecondsHigh(g2d, nums[secondsLeft], 5.6 * offset);
        drawCSecondsHigh(g2d, nums[secondsLeft], 5.6 * offset);
        drawDSecondsHigh(g2d, nums[secondsLeft], 5.6 * offset);
        drawESecondsHigh(g2d, nums[secondsLeft], 5.6 * offset);
        drawFSecondsHigh(g2d, nums[secondsLeft], 5.6 * offset);
        drawGSecondsHigh(g2d, nums[secondsLeft], 5.6 * offset);

        drawASecondsLow(g2d, nums[secondsRight], 6.6 * offset);
        drawBSecondsLow(g2d, nums[secondsRight], 6.6 * offset);
        drawCSecondsLow(g2d, nums[secondsRight], 6.6 * offset);
        drawDSecondsLow(g2d, nums[secondsRight], 6.6 * offset);
        drawESecondsLow(g2d, nums[secondsRight], 6.6 * offset);
        drawFSecondsLow(g2d, nums[secondsRight], 6.6 * offset);
        drawGSecondsLow(g2d, nums[secondsRight], 6.6 * offset);
    }

    private GradientPaint getColor(byte val, int shift) {
        int a = 255 * (val >> shift) & 1;
        if (!switchGradient) {
            if (a == 0)
                return new GradientPaint(0, 0, colorOff, (int) mainWidth, (int) mainHeight, colorOff);
            else {
                actualGradient = new GradientPaint(0, 0, colorStart, 1 + rateOfChange, 1 + rateOfChange, colorEnd);
                return actualGradient;
            }
        } else {
            if (a == 0)
                return new GradientPaint(0, 0, colorOff, (int) mainWidth, (int) mainHeight, colorOff);
            else {
                actualGradient = new GradientPaint(0, 0, colorEnd, 1 + rateOfChange, 1 + rateOfChange, colorStart);
                return actualGradient;
            }
        }
    }

    // Number hours left

    private void drawAHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape a = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(60, 20, 78, 18, 10, 10);

        originalCoordinates[0][0][0] = 60;
        originalCoordinates[0][0][1] = 20;
        originalCoordinates[0][1][0] = 78;
        originalCoordinates[0][1][1] = 18;

        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 6));
        g2d.fill(a);
        g2d.draw(a);
    }

    private void drawBHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape b = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(140, 40, 18, 98, 10, 10);

        originalCoordinates[1][0][0] = 140;
        originalCoordinates[1][0][1] = 40;
        originalCoordinates[1][1][0] = 18;
        originalCoordinates[1][1][1] = 98;

        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 5));
        g2d.fill(b);
        g2d.draw(b);
    }

    private void drawCHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape c = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(140, 160, 18, 98, 10, 10);

        originalCoordinates[2][0][0] = 140;
        originalCoordinates[2][0][1] = 160;
        originalCoordinates[2][1][0] = 18;
        originalCoordinates[2][1][1] = 98;

        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 4));
        g2d.fill(c);
        g2d.draw(c);
    }

    private void drawDHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape d = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(60, 260, 78, 18, 10, 10);

        originalCoordinates[3][0][0] = 60;
        originalCoordinates[3][0][1] = 260;
        originalCoordinates[3][1][0] = 78;
        originalCoordinates[3][1][1] = 18;

        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 3));
        g2d.fill(d);
        g2d.draw(d);
    }

    private void drawEHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape e = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(40, 160, 18, 98, 10, 10);

        originalCoordinates[4][0][0] = 40;
        originalCoordinates[4][0][1] = 160;
        originalCoordinates[4][1][0] = 18;
        originalCoordinates[4][1][1] = 98;

        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 2));
        g2d.fill(e);
        g2d.draw(e);
    }

    private void drawFHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape f = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(40, 40, 18, 98, 10, 10);

        originalCoordinates[5][0][0] = 40;
        originalCoordinates[5][0][1] = 40;
        originalCoordinates[5][1][0] = 18;
        originalCoordinates[5][1][1] = 98;

        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 1));
        g2d.fill(f);
        g2d.draw(f);
    }

    private void drawGHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape g = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(60, 140, 78, 18, 10, 10);

        originalCoordinates[6][0][0] = 60;
        originalCoordinates[6][0][1] = 140;
        originalCoordinates[6][1][0] = 78;
        originalCoordinates[6][1][1] = 18;

        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 0));
        g2d.fill(g);
        g2d.draw(g);
    }

    // Number Hours Right

    private void drawAHoursLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape a = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[0][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[0][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[0][1][0], originalCoordinates[0][1][1], 10, 10);

        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 6));
        g2d.fill(a);
        g2d.draw(a);
    }

    private void drawBHoursLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        XbHL = originalCoordinates[1][0][0] + offset;
        widthbHL = originalCoordinates[1][1][0];
        YbHL = originalCoordinates[1][0][1];
        heightbHL = originalCoordinates[1][1][1];

        Shape b = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(XbHL, YbHL, widthbHL, heightbHL, 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 5));
        g2d.fill(b);
        g2d.draw(b);
    }

    private void drawCHoursLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        XcHL = originalCoordinates[2][0][0] + offset;
        widthcHL = originalCoordinates[2][1][0];
        YcHL = originalCoordinates[2][0][1];
        heightcHL = originalCoordinates[2][1][1];

        Shape c = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(XcHL, YcHL, widthcHL, heightcHL, 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 4));
        g2d.fill(c);
        g2d.draw(c);
    }

    private void drawDHoursLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape d = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[3][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[3][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[3][1][0], originalCoordinates[3][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 3));
        g2d.fill(d);
        g2d.draw(d);
    }

    private void drawEHoursLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape e = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[4][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[4][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[4][1][0], originalCoordinates[4][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 2));
        g2d.fill(e);
        g2d.draw(e);
    }

    private void drawFHoursLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape f = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[5][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[5][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[5][1][0], originalCoordinates[5][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 1));
        g2d.fill(f);
        g2d.draw(f);
    }

    private void drawGHoursLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape g = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[6][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[6][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[6][1][0], originalCoordinates[6][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 0));
        g2d.fill(g);
        g2d.draw(g);
    }

    // 2 Points

    private void drawPointUp(Graphics2D g2d, double offset) {
        double radius = widthbHL / 2.0;
        double diameter = radius * 2;

        if (dotsIluminated % 2 == 0)
            g2d.setPaint(actualGradient);
        else
            g2d.setPaint(colorOff);
        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(radius + offset, (heightbHL / 2.0) - radius + YbHL, diameter, diameter);
        g2d.fill(circle);
        g2d.draw(circle);
    }

    private void drawPointDown(Graphics2D g2d, double offset) {

        double radius = widthcHL / 2.0;
        double diameter = radius * 2;
        if (dotsIluminated % 2 == 0)
            g2d.setPaint(actualGradient);
        else
            g2d.setPaint(colorOff);
        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(radius + offset, (heightcHL / 2.0) - radius + YcHL, diameter, diameter);
        g2d.fill(circle);
        g2d.draw(circle);

    }

    // Number Minutes High

    private void drawAMinutesHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape a = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[0][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[0][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[0][1][0], originalCoordinates[0][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 6));
        g2d.fill(a);
        g2d.draw(a);
    }

    private void drawBMinutesHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape b = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[1][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[1][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[1][1][0], originalCoordinates[1][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 5));
        g2d.fill(b);
        g2d.draw(b);
    }

    private void drawCMinutesHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape c = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[2][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[2][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[2][1][0], originalCoordinates[2][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 4));
        g2d.fill(c);
        g2d.draw(c);
    }

    private void drawDMinutesHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape d = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[3][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[3][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[3][1][0], originalCoordinates[3][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 3));
        g2d.fill(d);
        g2d.draw(d);
    }

    private void drawEMinutesHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape e = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[4][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[4][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[4][1][0], originalCoordinates[4][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 2));
        g2d.fill(e);
        g2d.draw(e);
    }

    private void drawFMinutesHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape f = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[5][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[5][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[5][1][0], originalCoordinates[5][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 1));
        g2d.fill(f);
        g2d.draw(f);
    }

    private void drawGMinutesHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape g = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[6][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[6][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[6][1][0], originalCoordinates[6][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 0));
        g2d.fill(g);
        g2d.draw(g);
    }

    // Number Minutes Low

    private void drawAMinutesLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape a = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[0][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[0][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[0][1][0], originalCoordinates[0][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 6));
        g2d.fill(a);
        g2d.draw(a);
    }

    private void drawBMinutesLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        XbML = originalCoordinates[1][0][0] + offset;
        widthbML = originalCoordinates[1][1][0];
        YbML = originalCoordinates[1][0][1];
        heightbML = originalCoordinates[1][1][1];

        Shape b = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(XbML, YbML, widthbML, heightbML, 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 5));
        g2d.fill(b);
        g2d.draw(b);
    }

    private void drawCMinutesLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        XcML = originalCoordinates[2][0][0] + offset;
        widthcML = originalCoordinates[2][1][0];
        YcML = originalCoordinates[2][0][1];
        heightcML = originalCoordinates[2][1][1];

        Shape c = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(XcML, YcML, widthcML, heightcML, 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 4));
        g2d.fill(c);
        g2d.draw(c);
    }

    private void drawDMinutesLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape d = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[3][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[3][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[3][1][0], originalCoordinates[3][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 3));
        g2d.fill(d);
        g2d.draw(d);
    }

    private void drawEMinutesLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape e = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[4][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[4][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[4][1][0], originalCoordinates[4][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 2));
        g2d.fill(e);
        g2d.draw(e);
    }

    private void drawFMinutesLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape f = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[5][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[5][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[5][1][0], originalCoordinates[5][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 1));
        g2d.fill(f);
        g2d.draw(f);
    }

    private void drawGMinutesLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape g = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[6][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[6][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[6][1][0], originalCoordinates[6][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 0));
        g2d.fill(g);
        g2d.draw(g);
    }

    private void drawPointSUp(Graphics2D g2d, double offset) {
        double radius = widthbML / 2.0;
        double diameter = radius * 2;

        if (dotsIluminated % 2 == 0)
            g2d.setPaint(actualGradient);
        else
            g2d.setPaint(colorOff);
        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(radius + offset, (heightbML / 2.0) - radius + YbML, diameter, diameter);
        g2d.fill(circle);
        g2d.draw(circle);
    }

    private void drawPointSDown(Graphics2D g2d, double offset) {
        double radius = widthcML / 2.0;
        double diameter = radius * 2;
        if (dotsIluminated % 2 == 0)
            g2d.setPaint(actualGradient);
        else
            g2d.setPaint(colorOff);
        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(radius + offset, (heightcML / 2.0) - radius + YcML, diameter, diameter);
        g2d.fill(circle);
        g2d.draw(circle);
    }

    // Number Seconds High

    private void drawASecondsHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape a = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[0][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[0][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[0][1][0], originalCoordinates[0][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 6));
        g2d.fill(a);
        g2d.draw(a);
    }

    private void drawBSecondsHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape b = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[1][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[1][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[1][1][0], originalCoordinates[1][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 5));
        g2d.fill(b);
        g2d.draw(b);
    }

    private void drawCSecondsHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape c = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[2][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[2][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[2][1][0], originalCoordinates[2][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 4));
        g2d.fill(c);
        g2d.draw(c);
    }

    private void drawDSecondsHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape d = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[3][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[3][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[3][1][0], originalCoordinates[3][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 3));
        g2d.fill(d);
        g2d.draw(d);
    }

    private void drawESecondsHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape e = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[4][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[4][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[4][1][0], originalCoordinates[4][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 2));
        g2d.fill(e);
        g2d.draw(e);
    }

    private void drawFSecondsHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape f = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[5][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[5][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[5][1][0], originalCoordinates[5][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 1));
        g2d.fill(f);
        g2d.draw(f);
    }

    private void drawGSecondsHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape g = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[6][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[6][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[6][1][0], originalCoordinates[6][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 0));
        g2d.fill(g);
        g2d.draw(g);
    }

    // Number Seconds Low

    private void drawASecondsLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape a = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[0][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[0][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[0][1][0], originalCoordinates[0][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 6));
        g2d.fill(a);
        g2d.draw(a);
    }

    private void drawBSecondsLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape b = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[1][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[1][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[1][1][0], originalCoordinates[1][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 5));
        g2d.fill(b);
        g2d.draw(b);
    }

    private void drawCSecondsLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape c = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[2][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[2][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[2][1][0], originalCoordinates[2][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 4));
        g2d.fill(c);
        g2d.draw(c);
    }

    private void drawDSecondsLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape d = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[3][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[3][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[3][1][0], originalCoordinates[3][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 3));
        g2d.fill(d);
        g2d.draw(d);
    }

    private void drawESecondsLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape e = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[4][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[4][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[4][1][0], originalCoordinates[4][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 2));
        g2d.fill(e);
        g2d.draw(e);
    }

    private void drawFSecondsLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape f = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[5][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[5][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[5][1][0], originalCoordinates[5][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 1));
        g2d.fill(f);
        g2d.draw(f);
    }

    private void drawGSecondsLow(Graphics2D g2d, byte val, double offset) {
        Shape g = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(originalCoordinates[6][0][0] + offset, originalCoordinates[6][0][1],
                originalCoordinates[6][1][0], originalCoordinates[6][1][1], 10, 10);
        g2d.setPaint(getColor(val, 0));
        g2d.fill(g);
        g2d.draw(g);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your example looks like it's 1fps. You'd need something around 60fps I would think.

Comment: Rather than re-creating gradients, you can perhaps store them in a collection and swap within the timer

Comment: It looks to me like you have two timers, one to change the time and one to change the gradient. However, the code you posted doesn't do anything. All you do is set the value of some variables. Nowhere do you ever do any repainting of the component with the new variables so the gradient only changes every second when the time changes.. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem so we don't have to guess what you may, or may not be doing.

Comment: @camickr made some changes based on your suggestions, now the animation works fine, post updated to show the changes and give more code if needed

Comment: @Angelixus, 700 lines of code is way to much. We are only interested in the context of the question you are asking. So your real question is "I have two timers, why does the component painting only change once a second?". You would then create an "MCVE" that demonstrates this concept. This code would be about 20 - 30 lines of code because you don't need anything fancy to demonstrate a basic concept. `made some changes based on your suggestions` - how is anybody supposed to guess what you changed? Tell us! I added an answer so you can "accept" the answer and let everybody know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot find the way to make a fast and smooth color transition, either smooth but slow or fast but laggy, how can I do it?

It looks to me like you have two timers, one to change the time and one to change the gradient.

However, the code you posted for the second timer doesn't really do anything. All you do is set the value of some variables. Nowhere do you ever do any repainting of the component with the new variables so the gradient only changes every second when the time changes.

So I would suggest that you need to add a `repaint()` to the `ActionListener` of the second timer. This will allow gradient changes to occur at the interval you specify in addition to painting the time every second.